# Updating wordpress child themes without deleting previous versions

Tags: php, wordpress

I've built a wordpress child theme for a client and currently deploy each version as a manual .zip theme upload by having to rename each .zip file to a unique identifier (i.e. newtheme-2017-06-07.zip) and then deleting the previous version manually.

Is there a way to upload child themes via wordpress admin so that it overwrites any theme with the same name? I don't want to be going down the route of using FTP to manually overwrite the theme.

I'd also be keen to hear how the update API works so that a customer gets alerted in the admin section that an update is available. So far my searches have been particularly unsuccessful.

Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: If I remember correctly, cant you just open the Themes panel, click the change theme button, and from there select to upload new child theme from local drive. So long as the parent theme is there, and the current child theme carries the same name, then uploading the replacement through the Themes panel should overwrite your current theme. If not, you could just delete the child in the Themes folder and upload a new one the same way.

Comment: Maybe [GitHub - YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker: A custom update checker for WordPress](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker)